# Ohai usage to pull kernel patch and date

Tags: chef-infra

How to use Ohai to pull the kernel version from each machine and patched date and redirect the output to a log with tag Collen separated .

Hostname:kernalpatch:date append to a log file .

How to use Ohai to pull the kernel version and installed date

Comment: Do you want to use the `ohai` command line, or use the data from within a cookbook? Any details on what you have attempted will be appreciated.

Comment: you can use/write custom plugins for the same 
https://docs.chef.io/ohai_custom/

Comment: Hi , I want to collect kernel , updates and install date and push this information with colon separated to syslog with tags using cookbook . So I can collect the data in splunk for dashboard as the data are ingested to splunk .